# Tangent to circle from external point.p

Tags: c++, math, opencv, geometry

I want to draw two tangents to a circle whose centre(x1,y1) and radius(r) is known and the tangent lines passes through an external point (x0,y0), Given the above information how can I find the point of tangency of these two lines with circle. Thanks in advance

P.S. i need to do this in C++

Comment: Sorry, I was unable to post image for better explanation of scenario..

Comment: So do you know from geometry, how to solve this task? In fact you know hypotenuse(you know both it's points) and cathetus(radius), this allows you to find a tangent point, then you can find tangent itself. If you know tangent, you can draw it.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thales%27_theorem

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! This question is more like a maths question, and there is a great Q&A site for that: math.stackexchange.com

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about mathematics.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some clues to compute tangent points at practice:

1. Shift all the points to make zero-centered circle (`P' = P0 - Center`)
2. Scale to make unit-radius circle (`x^2+y^2=1, P = P'/R`)
   [image]
3. Radius-vector from coord. origin to tangent point is perpendicular to tangent, so their scalar product iz zero:

   ```
   x*(X-x)+y*(Y-y)=0
   x*X + y*Y = x^2 +y^2 = 1    
   y = (1 - x*X)/Y
   ```
4. Substitute y in circle equation, solve this quadratic equation for x, then find y

   ```
   x^2*(X^2+Y^2)+x*(-2X)+(1-Y^2)=0
   ```
5. Restore original scale and offset

Delphi implementation:

```
//finds tangent points to circle from external point (XX, YY)
//returns number of tangents (0, 1, 2)
function GetTangentPointsAtCircle(CenterX, CenterY, R, XX, YY: Double;
                                 var XT0, YT0, XT1, YT1: Double): Integer;
var
  nx, ny, xy, tx0, tx1, D: Double;
begin
  if R = 0 then //this behavior can be modified
    Exit(0);

  nx := (XX - CenterX) / R; //shift and scale
  ny := (YY - CenterY) / R;
  xy := nx * nx + ny * ny;

  if Math.SameValue(xy, 1.0) then begin //point lies at circumference, one tangent
    XT0 := XX;
    YT0 := YY;
    Exit(1);
  end;

  if xy < 1.0 then  //point lies inside the circle, no tangents
    Exit(0);

  //common case, two tangents
  Result := 2;
  D := ny * Sqrt(xy - 1);
  tx0 := (nx - D) / xy;
  tx1 := (nx + D) / xy;
  if ny <> 0 then begin //common case
    YT0 := CenterY + R * (1 - tx0 * nx) / ny;
    YT1 := CenterY + R * (1 - tx1 * nx) / ny;
  end else begin //point at the center horizontal, Y=0
    D := R * Sqrt(1 - tx0 * tx0);
    YT0 := CenterY + D;
    YT1 := CenterY - D;
  end;
  XT0 := CenterX + R * tx0; //restore scale and position
  XT1 := CenterX + R * tx1;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

*While I agree that the question is off topic and should be closed, I'll post an answer anyway since it might still help.*

Here is what I'd do: I'd compute the [polar line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pole_and_polar) of the circle, which you obtain by multiplying the [matrix representation of the circle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_representation_of_conic_sections) with the [homogeneous coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_coordinates) of the point, namely (x0, y0, 1). The resultinng vector (a,b,c) describes a line {(x,y)|ax+by+c=0} which you can intersect with the circle to find your points of tangency.

The above works not only for circles, but for arbitrary smooth [conics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conic_section).